# SAS concatenating multiple variables with various formats

Tags: sas

I have a data set where I need to combine multiple variables into a `record_id`.
However some of these variables are formatted in such a way that `Variable A = 1` because 1st/ 26 and for variable `C` Feb = 2 because it is the second month.

```
    a b   c   d e f g   PersonalID

    O S Feb   1 1 0 1   151921101
    S A MAR   0 0 0 0   19130000
    B E JUN   1 3 1 1   2561311

    data test;
    set Redcap;
    PersonalID=cats(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
    keep PersonalID a b c d e f g;
    run;
```

How do I change it so that it comes out not with the numeric format, but with the character format?

So that it appears as

```
    PersonalID
    OSFeb1101
    SAMar0000
    BEJun1311
```

Answer (score 1):

`cats` is doing the default conversion (`best12.`, probably).  If you want the variable's formatted value, you want to use `vvalue` to get that.

```
personalID = cats(vvalue(a),vvalue(b),...)
```